# Preserve original website formatting inside ckeditor?

Tags: css, ckeditor

I'm trying to do a simple wysiwyg editor and I am trying to edit [this page](http://makehugeprofit.com/index.php?p=menu).

I inserted that code [into my editor](http://makehugeprofit.com/editor/editor.php) and included the original css file from the website, yet it seems like ckeditor is putting its own tags around the overall content which breaks the original design. Is there a simple way to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inline editing](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline) is what you want to do there. Simply render the website (component) in your admin panel, using your default, frontend styles and [create inline editors](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) for all editable fields. Finally serialize contents of editors.

Comment: Actually this would be a more solid allaround solution than mine. I'll still leave my answer if others want to add custom styles to a non-inline editor.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor uses CSS from `ckeditor/contents.css` - you have to add your CSS  there.

Your file is visible at `http://makehugeprofit.com/editor/ckeditor/contents.css?t=E0LB` and as you can see, it doesn't contain much. How did do "included the original css file from the website"? Merge it with contents.css and you'll have greater luck.

The editable area is an iframe and thus not in the same CSS space as your surrounding site.